# Angular modules managing issue

Tags: angular

I am trying to well manage folders in my Angular app.

I created a */components* one for shared components and a */pages* one for page components.
Each of them have a module, and the problem is that I cannot access shared components from a page component.

Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-rgb-m7qqlr

Thanks for help !

Comment: you have homecomponent declared twice in your pages module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the shared module in the page module.
This will make the components in the shared module available
to the page module.

Comment: looking at his sandbox code he already has that in there

Comment: It's missing in the class PagesModule.

Comment: Why importing ComponentsModule in the AppModule does not provide components for the whole app ?

Comment: That's part of the concept of modules (https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules). Actually you don't have to use (sub) modules. But they help you to structure your code and make it reusable.